# Angular2 - Testing ngOninit in Components

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-directives

I have a listing component with following code:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/router';

import { Employee } from '../models/employee';
import { EmployeeListServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-list-service.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'employee-list',
  template: `
    <ul class="employees">
  <li *ngFor="#employee of employees">
    <a [routerLink]="['EmployeeDetail', {id: employee.id}]">
      <span class="badge">{{employee.id}}</span>
      {{employee.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [EmployeeListServiceComponent]
})

export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees: Employee[];
  public errorMessage: string;

  constructor(
    private _listingService: EmployeeListServiceComponent
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._listingService.getEmployees().subscribe(
                     employees => this.employees = employees,
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error
                   );
  }
}
```

I wish to write unit tests for the `ngOninit` hook. I have written following test:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/main/ambient/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts" />

import {
    it,
    describe,
    expect,
    TestComponentBuilder,
    injectAsync,
    setBaseTestProviders,
    beforeEachProviders,
} from "angular2/testing";
import { Component, provide, ApplicationRef, OnInit } from "angular2/core";
import {
    TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from "angular2/platform/testing/browser";
import {
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT,
    APP_BASE_HREF
} from 'angular2/router';
import {XHRBackend, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import { MockApplicationRef } from 'angular2/src/mock/mock_application_ref';
import {MockBackend } from "angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Employee } from '../models/employee';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './list.component';
import { EmployeeListServiceComponent } from '../services/employee-list-service.component';


class MockEmployeeListServiceComponent {

    getEmployees () {
        return Observable.of([
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Abhinav Mishra"
            }
        ]);
    }
}


@Component({
    template: '<employee-list></employee-list>',
    directives: [EmployeeListComponent],
    providers: [MockEmployeeListServiceComponent]
})
class TestMyList {}


describe('Employee List Tests', () => {
    setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

    beforeEachProviders(() => {
        return [
            ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
            ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            provide(EmployeeListServiceComponent, {useClass: MockEmployeeListServiceComponent}),
            provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
            provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}),
            provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: EmployeeListComponent}),
            provide(ApplicationRef, {useClass: MockApplicationRef})
        ]
    });

    it('Should be true',
        injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
            return tcb
                .createAsync(TestMyList)
                .then((fixture) => {
                    fixture.detectChanges();
                    var compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
                    console.log(compiled.innerHTML);
                    expect(true).toBe(true);
                });
        })
    );
});
```

However, the output of `console.log` in the test is an empty `ul` tag as follows:

```
 '<employee-list>
    <ul class="employees">
  <!--template bindings={}-->
</ul>
  </employee-list>'
```

Can anyone suggest me the proper way of writing unit tests for component hooks?

**SOLUTION**

Mock the http request in the `injectAsync` block as follows:

```
backend.connections.subscribe(
                (connection:MockConnection) => {
                    var options = new ResponseOptions({
                        body: [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "name": "Abhinav Mishra"
                            }
                        ]
                    });

                    var response = new Response(options);

                    connection.mockRespond(response);
                }
            );
```

However now i am getting another error as follows:

```
Failed: EXCEPTION: Component "EmployeeListComponent" has no route config. in [['EmployeeDetail', {id: employee.id}] in EmployeeListComponent@3:7]
        ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component "EmployeeListComponent" has no route config.
        ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
        Error: Component "EmployeeListComponent" has no route config.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call async code in `ngOnInit()` you can't assume it is completed when `console.log(...)` is executed. `this.employees` is only set when the callback you passed to `subscribe(...)` gets called after the response arrived.

If you use [MockBackend](https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend) you can control the response and after the response was passed you have to run `fixture.detectChanges()` again to make the component re-render with the updated data, then you can read `innerHTML` and expect it to contain the rendered content.

Comment: your solution worked. But now I am getting following error. Can you suggest a work around?

 `Failed: EXCEPTION: Component "EmployeeListComponent" has no route config. in [['EmployeeDetail', {id: employee.id}] in EmployeeListComponent@3:7]
        ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Component "EmployeeListComponent" has no route config.`

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011972/component-undefined-has-no-route-config-aka-how-to-configure-angular-2-router-fo?rq=1

Comment: still getting the same error. can you please add a sample code here ?